# Why isn't JSON serializing all values and how can I force it?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

My code is below, it throws an exception because prv and pub are equal. It only serializes 2 members. I looked at RSAParameters and maybe it isn't showing me some attributes because I'm using .net core 2 but I see nothing to say not to serialize those members. Is there a way to force json.net to serialize those members? How do I save my private key? Write a function by hand?

```
using(var rsa = System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.Create())
{
    var prv = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
    var pub = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
    var prvtext = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(prv);
    var pubtext = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pub);
    if (prvtext == pubtext)
        throw new Exception();
}
```

The class is

```
#region Assembly System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
// C:\Users\acidzombie24\.nuget\packages\microsoft.netcore.app\2.0.0\ref\netcoreapp2.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll
#endregion

namespace System.Security.Cryptography
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Represents the standard parameters for the System.Security.Cryptography.RSA algorithm.
    public struct RSAParameters
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Represents the D parameter for the System.Security.Cryptography.RSA algorithm.
        public byte[] D;
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Represents the DP parameter for the System.Security.Cryptography.RSA algorithm.
        public byte[] DP;
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Represents the DQ parameter for the System.Security.Cryptography.RSA algorithm.
        public byte[] DQ;
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Represents the Exponent parameter for the System.Security.Cryptography.RSA algorithm.
        public byte[] Exponent;
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Represents the InverseQ parameter for the System.Security.Cryptography.RSA algorithm.
        public byte[] InverseQ;
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Represents the Modulus parameter for the System.Security.Cryptography.RSA algorithm.
        public byte[] Modulus;
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Represents the P parameter for the System.Security.Cryptography.RSA algorithm.
        public byte[] P;
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Represents the Q parameter for the System.Security.Cryptography.RSA algorithm.
        public byte[] Q;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe only public properties by default are serialized, not fields. Which two are showing?

Comment: It serializes everything unless marked. I guess dotnet core libraries don't show the NonSerialized attribute in visual studios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, fields on the `RSAParameters` struct are marked with `[NonSerialized]`.

[Here's the github commit that fixes that](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/commit/7eed79faf47e8e8dbe1645fb002e52c306867347#diff-e2fd7b90687cb72a21ef576691e849e5L9), or an [image of the commit in case the link dies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfgqL.png).

Before that commit only the `Exponent` and `Modulus` properties were allowed to be serialized.

You'll need to wait for that commit to make it to a nuget package release. Based on [the pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/22862) this will be in version 2.1.0.

Comment: Ah! and dotnet 2 just came out a month ago so I guess it will be awhile. I guess I'll write code by hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom `DefaultContractResolver` to ignore the effect of `[NonSerialized]`:

```
public class RSAContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
  protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
  {
    IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
    if (type == typeof(RSAParameters))
    {
        foreach(var property in properties)
        {
            property.Ignored = false;
        }
    }

    return properties;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new RSAContractResolver() };
var prvtext = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(prv, settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `CustomConverter`... Something like this:

```
public class RsaConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(RSAParameters);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var param = new RSAParameters();

        param.D = Convert.FromBase64String((string)obj["D"]);
        // other properties...

        return param;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = (JObject)JToken.FromObject(value);
        RSAParameters param = (RSAParameters)value;

        if (obj["D"] == null && param.D != null) obj.Add("D", Convert.ToBase64String(param.D));
        // other properties...

        obj.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```